# What's the error with this BASH regex script?

Tags: regex, string, bash, comparison

I'm trying to make a program that reads in `n` strings and checks them for pertaining to a regex pattern: XXXXX1234X where X is an uppercase character and {1,2,3,4} is any digit. As far as I checked, the regex pattern is correct. The problem seems to be in the input and comparison of strings.

```
read n
i=0
declare -a str
while [ $i -lt $n ]
do
    read 'str[$i]'
    i=$((i+1))
done


i=0
while [ $i -lt $n ]
do

    [[ $(str[$i])  =~ ^([A-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([A-Z]){1}$ ]] && echo YES || echo NO
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: `$()` is for command substitution; `${}` is for parameter expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a minor modification to your code, I replaced the `(` and `)` with `{` `}` in the regex test:

```
[[ ${str[$i]}  =~ ^...
```

Ran some test and it worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
read n
i=0
declare -a str
while [ $i -lt $n ]
do
    read 'str[$i]'
    i=$((i+1))
done

i=0
while [ $i -lt $n ]
do
    [[ ${str[$i]}  =~ ^([A-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([A-Z]){1}$ ]] && echo YES || echo NO
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: What's the difference between {} and () in this case?

Comment: Glad it helped! `$(...)` executes a subshell, inside it the command `str[$i]` (that is executed as `[number]`) most likely will produce an error that goes under the table because is kept inside the subshell. `${variable}` is kind of an extended notation for `$variable`, it means the same but let you apply some operations prior to adquire the variable value, like p.e., the array index operator `[$i]`, another example `${#variable}` returns the length of the deferrenced variable